# How to remove the 1st character of a string?

Tags: r

Please could someone help me with removing the first character from a column string variable ("T")?

```
 > head(ECGHR_long)
id  T ECG_HR
1 2003 T0     70
2 2004 T0     98
3 2008 T0     93
4 2010 T0     71
5 2018 T0     90
6 2019 T0     60
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply replace the letter part by an empty string:

```
as.numeric(sub('[A-Za-z]', '', c('T0', 'T1')))
```

The regular expression `[A-Za-z]` matches all letters, and replaces it by `''`. The `as.numeric` casts the result to a number.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of the first character, whatever it is:

```
substring(ECGHR_long$ECG_HR, 2)
```

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks.